# Adding list of acronyms without a title

Tags: titles, multicol, acro

I am using the `acro` package, and I have so many abbreviations that it fills more than one page. Therefore I would like to have two columns in the abbreviation list, and I have used the `multicols` environment for that.

However the problem is then that the title itself of the `\printacronyms` command is placed in the first column, and not before the two columns start. Setting the name to nothing just created a blank space, but does anyone know how to remove the title entirely? Or alternatively a different solution for creating two columns in an automatic abbreviation list?

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{multicol}

%Defining acronyms
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\DeclareAcronym{LI}{
  short = LI ,
  long  = Lorem ipsum ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{DSA}{
  short = DSA ,
  long  = Dolor sit amet ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{CAE}{
  short = CAE ,
  long  = Consectetuer adipiscing elit ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{SDE}{
  short = SDE ,
  long  = Sed do eiusmod ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{TI}{
  short = TI ,
  long  = Tempor incididunt ,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printacronyms[name={List of abbreviations}] %Prints abbr.
\end{multicols}

%Dummy text
\vspace{3cm}
Lorem ipsum (\ac{LI}) dolor sit amet (\ac{DSA}), consectetur adipiscing elit (\ac{CAE}), sed do eiusmod ({\ac{SDE}) tempor incididunt (\ac{TI}) ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the option `heading=none`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{multicol}

%Defining acronyms
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\DeclareAcronym{LI}{
  short = LI ,
  long  = Lorem ipsum ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{DSA}{
  short = DSA ,
  long  = Dolor sit amet ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{CAE}{
  short = CAE ,
  long  = Consectetuer adipiscing elit ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{SDE}{
  short = SDE ,
  long  = Sed do eiusmod ,
}
\DeclareAcronym{TI}{
  short = TI ,
  long  = Tempor incididunt ,
}

\begin{document}

\section{List of abbreviations}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \printacronyms[heading=none] %Prints abbr.
\end{multicols}

%Dummy text
\vspace{3cm}
Lorem ipsum (\ac{LI}) dolor sit amet (\ac{DSA}), consectetur adipiscing elit (\ac{CAE}), sed do eiusmod ({\ac{SDE}) tempor incididunt (\ac{TI}) ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

There might be more elegant ways to do this, since `acro` allows you to define your own templates, see: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I thought I already checked that :)

Comment: I would recommend to use `\begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{List of abbrevations}]` to avoid page breaks between the section heading an the `multicols` environment. See also the example in section 2 of the `multicol` manual.

Comment: @cabohah -- Good idea